# Remove drupal parameters from form submitted via POST

Tags: 7, redirection, commerce

When I submit form created with Form API, the POST variable contains values like form_token, form_build and form_id.

The problem is, I need to send submitted form values to external website. Is it possible to remove such values from POST request?

In particular, I am implementing [redirection callback to commerce payment method](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!payment!commerce_payment.api.php/function/CALLBACK_commerce_payment_method_redirect_form/DC)

This callback is defined within Drupal Commerce. The callback works OK, but how can I remove the mentioned form parameters? (The third party payment service does not accept them in received POST variable).

I am not sure whether I can just unset them in hook_form_alter. This callback is just part of the order process and I am not sure if I  can just unset it.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a call to external website using [drupal_http_request](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/7) in form submit handler.. Define extra submit handler using hook_form_alter and

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'YOUR_FORM_SUBMIT_HANDLER';
```

For Example

```
// Adds a submit handler/function for your form

function YOUR_FORM_SUBMIT_HANDLER($form, &$form_state) {

    $options = array();
    // Array keys are matching the key that the remote site accepts. URL encoding will be taken care later.
    $options['data'] = array(
        'firstName' => $form_state['values']['firstName'],
        'lastName' => $form_state['values']['lastName'],
        'email' => $form_state['values']['email'],
        'name' => $form_state['values']['name'],
        'phone' => $form_state['values']['phone'],
    );
    $options['data'] = http_build_query($options['data']);
    $options['method'] => 'POST';
    $url = 'https://[url path to external site]'; 

    // Put your additional headers here. Cookie can be set as well. 
    $headers = array('Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    $options['headers'] => $headers;

    // Submits data to the remote server from the drupal server. User will remain in the Drupal form submission chain.
    $response = drupal_http_request($url, $options);

}
```